# probability uppercase for specific word in c#

Tags: c#

I want algorithm for all probability for uppercase for this word **hgmsolgomd**

I tried this code but this convert the word not letter by letter and not all probability

```
string name = "hgmsolgomd";
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            string newName = name.ToUpper();
        }
```

Comment: I don't think "probability" means what you think it means. What is the expected result?

Comment: all probabilites for this word in uppercase like: hgMsolgomd, hgmsolGomd , and so on

Comment: You mean "possibilities", not "probabilities".

Comment: ok, i want to print all possibilities :) for this word in uppercase

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct answer 
 Possible duplicate. The following post has the code for permutations of uppercase: stackoverflow.com/questions/905317/… -- this should cover your needs. – David Tansey 7 hours ago

Answer (score -1):

if even one capital letter includes to possibilities combination then:

```
  string text = "hgmsolgomd";

            int possibilitiesForAllCaps = (int)Math.Pow(2, text.Length) - 1;
```

There is "minus 1", because "hgmsolgomd" doesn't count, but say "hgmsolgom**D**" does.

Comment: Your code ignore content of a `text`

Comment: if we take first two letters ("hg"), then there are "hG","Hg","HG". Where do you see ignoring?

Comment: `possibilitiesForAllCaps` is only depends on source string length. It will have same result for "hg" and "HG"

Comment: @AleksAndreev the topic is for "hgmsolgomd". Not for all contents.

Comment: I think the OP wants to print out all variations, not count them.

Comment: I want all probabilites  of uppercase in all positions

Comment: yes, i want print all probabilites not count them